# After git cloning of repository just reuse node modules without download

Tags: node.js, ember.js, gruntjs, bower

I am working on client side application.
We are using the following technologies:
  git, node, ember, grunt, sass and other components

Once I cloned the application from git server every time I have to do make tooling to download all the necessary node, sass and bower components and it will take 200MB of data will be downloaded and time consumed.

Is there any solution with out downloading the node modules the app has to run by reusing the Already downloaded modules with out make tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include the node modules in your git repository as well. You'll still have to download them (there's no way around fetching the modules somehow). I'm guessing in your `.gitignore` you have a line that looks like `node_modules`. If you remove that line, the modules will be included in your git repository and will be included when you do a git clone.

Be aware that there are a couple of drawbacks to this method:

- Git repo size will increase significantly
- Modules that have to be compiled likely won't work on other machines, especially different OS's (developing on a Mac, deploying on Linux, for example).

Comment: If i copy the node modules from previous working directory to the cloned directory . will it work?

Comment: Afer adding the node modules when I run grunt server i am getting the followwing error (Warning: Errno::ENOENT on line ["33"] of /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-1.0.1/lib/compass) and my .gitignore files contain the following lines.                                                              temp
dist
.grunt
.sass-cache
.tmp
app/bower_components
*.sw[po]                                                                     could you please look into this

Comment: Hey thanks for your great help.it works for me with out changing the file .gitignore and copied bower components